# position_dodge works differently depending on location of fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Can anyone explain why this is the case? If I use the fill aesthetic in the main call, I get the result I want. If I use it in the call to `geom_bar`, I don't. I'm sure there must be a simple reason, if anyone could enlighten me, I'd be grateful.

'Correct':

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x = c("One", "Two", "Three", "One", "Two", "Three"),
  y = c(12, 10, 11, 10, 12, 11),
  year = c("2016", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2017", "2017")
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = y), position = position_dodge(.9))
```

Result:

[image]

Other way:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", aes(fill = year)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = y), position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Comment: in the second case, `geom_text` does not know about which variable it is dodging over. If you add `fill = year` to the `geom_text`'s `aes` then it will work (but also give a warning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position_dodge` needs a `group` aesthetic to "dodge on".
The `fill` `aesthetic` silently creates a `group`  `aes`.

So if you put it in the main call `geom_text` will inherit the (hidden) `group` aes. If it's put in `geom_bar` then `geom_text` does not have a `group` and so it dodges on nothing.

You can veify by adding a `fill = year` to the `geom_text`. This will give a warning about  `unknown aesthetic` but will `dodge` the text position.